# Php: cut part of image

Tags: php

Hi my problem is the following:
I have a jpg or png  image file, white background. In this image there are many glasses pictures. My goal is to cut every single glasses picture and save in separate file.
Position and size of glasses pictures can vary. 
I have windows-based hosting service, can't install any third party software...
All this using PHP (I know its not besto choice for these tasks, but i have only PHP there)
Thanks!

Comment: How do you want the images cut out? Are you effectively asking how to crop the images in batch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260016/php-image-resize-and-cropping

Answer (score 0):

What you are proposing here amounts to image recognition and analysis. Which is a very challenging area of programming. Its also very computationally expensive - so PHP is far from the ideal platform. That your question is so vague, and that you want to implement this in PHP on a hosted server rather implies that you're a long way out of your depth.

Go grab a copy the [Gnu image manipulation program](http://www.gimp.org/) and do it by hand.